# Java Swing - Component Disappears After Mouse Enters JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm a beginner to Java and I'm trying to make an air-hockey program. In order to do this, I must first test to see if the mallet and puck are touching. I have created a program that allows me to do this. Here is the code for the Board:

```
package airhockey;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Board {
    static Mallet m;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Air Hockey");
        JPanel j = new JPanel();
        j.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        f.add(j);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        m = new Mallet();
        Puck p = new Puck();
        f.add(m);
        j.addMouseMotionListener(m);
        f.add(p);
        p.t.start();
    }
}
```

for the Mallet:

```
package airhockey;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Mallet extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
    int x = 300;
    int y = 200;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x-30, y-30, 60, 60);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getX() >= 570) x = 570;
        else if(e.getX() <= 30) x = 30;
        else x = e.getX();
        if(e.getY() >= 370) y = 370;
        else if(e.getY() <= 30) y = 30;
        else y = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

and for the Puck:

```
package airhockey;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Puck extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    int x = 300;
    int y = 200;
    int v = 0;
    int h = 0;
    Timer t = new Timer(20,this);
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x-20, y-20, 40, 40);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(Math.pow((x-Board.m.x)+(y-Board.m.y),2) <= 50) System.out.println("Touching");
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the Puck appears in the middle, but the Mallet is not there. However, when the mouse enters the Board, the puck disappears and the Mallet appears. Still, the console says "Touching" when the Mallet moves near to where the Puck was. Why does the Puck disappear when the mouse enters the board, and how can I make the Puck reappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your adding two components to the JFrame's contentPane, a container that uses BorderLayout by default, and so one component covers the other. I recommend that you change your program structure, that you have just a single JPanel to do all painting, and that you make your gui sprites be structured as logical and non-gui component classes. Meaning the Puck and Mallot classes would not extend JPanel but would have a `public void draw(Graphics g)` method that the painting JPanel would call within its paintComponent method.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new class called Panel which draws both of the components. The program now works exactly as I wanted it to.